# How to see live DOM updates with IE8 Developer tools

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

Is there a way to see live DOM updates with the IE8 Developer Tools?

It seems that it is just a snapshot of the DOM. Without pressing the refresh button (in the developer tool window) there's no way to see live DOM updates. It there a way to get it to behave more like Firebug?

Comment: +1 for letting me know you *can* hit F5 to see DOM updates. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

It also works with IE 8.

Comment: Yeah, my only reservation is having to keep adding/removing it from my project code.